Movie about a couple whose daughter died in a car accident
I started watching a movie last week, but I could not finish watching it. I do not remember its title and I hope that you would help me.
The movie is about a couple whose daughter dies in a car accident after her mother follows her in a car. The father then left his wife and moved to New Orleans from Indianapolis, IN. In New Orleans he lives in a house with a 16 years old girl who works as a stripper in a night club. 
Anyone knows the title of the movie?

Pretty sure I know what you're after, but I still urge you to add as many details as you can: year, country, possible actors etc. It'll improve your chances to get the right answer and for the question to remain open.

it is Welcome tho the Rileys, mattiav27 wrote the answer. thank you  :)

It could help tremendously if you could tell us where and when you watched it. Was it on TV? On which channel in which country? Could you employ the TV Guide to your aid? Did you rent it or stream it somewhere from? Is there a record to check what you rented/streamed?

@NapoleonWilson you do not need to down vote my question. I live in Albania and I watched it on tv. As I said in my previous comment, I got the answer thanks to mattiav27 so the question is closed. thanks anyway

@user1349390 First of all, where do you deduce from that I downvoted your question? Try not to base this simply on comments. That being said, I did indeed downvote. It is my right and duty to downvote content I deem not good or with not enough effort  put into it. Please don't take downvotes as personal attacks, they are merely a signal how the users see your question and every user is not only free but encouraged to downvote questions he deems not good ones without personally attacking the respective asker. And people have commented on the ways to improve the question, answered or not.

Could it be Welcome to the Rileys? A 2010 movie with  James Gandolfini, Kristen Stewart and Melissa Leo.
From IMDB:

A married couple loses their 15 year old daughter in a car accident
  after her and her boyfriend took off after Lois (the mother) goes
  looking for them. Doug, Lois's husband later meets a young girl at a
  club who says to be 22 and a stripper, but later he finds out she's a
  16 year old runaway. He tries to help her out by making her house
  nicer and teaching her proper language. Later, his wife meets the girl
  and becomes upset because she reminds her of her own daughter but a
  prostitute. The couple try to help the girl make a better life for
  herself.


yes, that's it. thank you very much
